# How to call a constructor which has an array type in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a contructor(Motor) in Motor class, and I want to call it in Contructor1 class, but i have an error when I do that.....and I don't know why.
I am learning java just from this week.

This is the code:

```
  class Motor{
        Motor(int type[]){
            int input;
            input=0;
            type = new int[4];
            for(int contor=0; contor<4; contor++){
                System.out.println("Ininsert the number of cylinders:");
                Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
                    input = stdin.nextInt();
                type[contor] = input;
                System.out.println("Motor with "+type[contor]+" cylinders.");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Contructor1 {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Motor motor_type;
            for(int con=0; con<4; con++){
                motor_type = new Motor();
            }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Please post the error, otherwise we can't really help you..

Answer (score 7):

It's not clear why you've put a parameter in the constructor in the first place - you're not *using* it:

```
Motor(int type[]){
    int input;
    input=0;
    type = new int[4];
```

In that last line, you're basically overwriting whatever value was passed in. Why are you doing that?

If you *do* want to keep it, you need to create an array to pass in from the caller, e.g.

```
int[] types = new int[4];
// Populate the array here...
motor_type = new Motor(types);
```

The code at the moment looks a little confused though - are you actually intending for a single instance of `Motor` to have multiple values, or are you *really* interested in having multiple instances of `Motor`?

As a side note, this syntax:

```
int type[]
```

is discouraged. You should keep the type information in one place:

```
int[] type
```

Additionally, it's odd that you have no fields in `Motor`, and you never use the value that you're creating in the calling code either.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor has an argument of type `int[]`, but you don't pass anything as argument. You need to create an array, and pass it as argument:

```
int[] type = new int[4];
Motor m = new Motor(type);
```

Note that this constructor argument isn't useful at all, since you don't do anything with it in the constructor. Instead, you overwrite it with a new array. I would simply remove the array argument.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass in[] as argument to `Motor` constructor.

like

```
 new Motor (new int[] {0,1,2,3});
```

As you have defined parametrized constructor in `Motor` class it won't create no-arg  constructor by default that why you are getting error on bellow line

```
 motor_type = new Motor();  // Error here , because no-arg constructor not defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
int intType[]={1,2,3}; //create some int array
Motor motor_type=new Motor(intType); //pass int array here
```